# Flickering Issue In DevExpress WinForms GridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, devexpress

**Hi All**

> I have developed a desktop application and that is currently running in an organization . I have used most of the DevExpress Win Controls in this application. This application runs continuesly 12 to 14 hours everyday. While running some time some controls in my **application starts flickering**. Mainly **Grid Controls Flickers**. I am consuming web service in this application. According to me that issue produces due to delay response in webservice call, but i am not sure about that. Can anyone tell me what can be a possible reson behind this issue?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: How are you updating the data in your grid?  Can you show some code?

Comment: Are you periodically polling the webservice (from the UI thread, perhaps on a Timer) and then refreshing the data in the GridControl with the response of the web service? It could simply be that the UI  is blocked momentarily, interfering with the painting of the GridControl until the web service call is completed. In this case, you might want to consider polling the web service from a non-UI thread, perhaps with a BackgroundWorker component.

Comment: Did you try `gridview.BeginUpdate();` and `gridview.EndUpdate();` ?